# When I try to install php artisan ui vue --auth I get 'array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array' error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I try to install `php artisan ui vue --auth` these errors are displaying. How can I fix this?

```
laravel verison:6.5.0
C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\admindash>php artisan ui vue --auth

   ErrorException  : array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null gi
ven

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\admindash\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Preset.php:
40
    36|
    37|         $packages = json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path('package.jso
n')), true);
    38|
    39|         $packages[$configurationKey] = static::updatePackageArray(
  > 40|             array_key_exists($configurationKey, $packages) ? $packages[$
configurationKey] : [],
    41|             $configurationKey
    42|         );
    43|
    44|         ksort($packages[$configurationKey]);

  Exception trace:

  1   array_key_exists("devDependencies")
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\admindash\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Preset.php
:40

  2   Laravel\Ui\Presets\Preset::updatePackages()
      C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\admindash\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.
```

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: value of $packages ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  if(is_array($packages) && array_key_exists($configurationKey, $packages)){
? $packages[$configurationKey] : [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's how I worked

```
 if(is_array($packages) && array_key_exists($configurationKey, $packages)){
        $packages[$configurationKey] ? $packages[$configurationKey] : [];


}
//ksort($packages[$configurationKey]);
```

Comment: Hi Yusuf! While this code may provide a solution to OP's problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It it could to be error with JSON. You should look to **package.json**
Maybe you have sign "**,**" in last "key":"value".

for Exemple

**with ERROR:**

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.10.0",
    }
```

**Correct version**:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.10.0"
    }
```